# Responsive dropdown menu conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been fiddling around with a menu-experiment that is based on 'responsive-nav.js' and trying to add dropdowns to it. All would be fine, but for some reason I am not able to get the dropdowns to appear right. Even with making them to absolute position within a relative container. I am sure it is something simple, but just can't get my head around it.
If I delete the script bit at the bottom it works but this way I loose the toggle-menu.

I created a lint for this:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5791486/dropdown2/index.html

---

The answer is as suggested below: overflow:visible, but to make the toggle fluid I had to create an extra media queries for this:

```
.js #nav {
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    max-height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    overflow: visible;
    zoom: 1;
    }

@media screen and (max-width: 40em) {
    .js #nav {
    overflow: hidden;
    }
}
```

That was it, Thanks again!!!!

Comment: modify #nav ul li:hover ul {top:100%} and .js #nav {overflow:visible}

Comment: Thanks for the reply chackorun yesser the solution was the overflow:visible. I just missed this out, but changing this almost solved the problem. The 50% was just for an experiment so I could see if the dropdown was still there. Many thanks for pushing me to the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Tou have to set `top: 100%;` on `#nav ul li:hover ul` to let the submenu align to the bottom of their parent.

```
#nav ul li:hover ul  {
    display: block;
    position:absolute;
    top:100%;
  }
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/UG9cy/

Comment: Thanks for your help SKeurentjes. The 50% was just to show the dropdown, but changing overflow:visible seems to made a break through for now.